# Disable snd_hda_intel power save mode in Void Linux on startup

Tags: audio, void-linux

I want to disable my sound card's power save mode persistently. After logging in KDE, I can run `echo 0 >| /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` manually in a root shell and this works.

None of the following methods for a persistent solution have the desired effect:

1. create */etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf* and put `options snd_hda_intel power_save=0` in it
2. in */etc/rc.local* add `echo 0 >| /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save`

Is there any way to debug why neither work or is there another method I am missing?